# Dynamically creating a new instance of IList's type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, ilist

My application is processing IList's. ILists of different user defined types. I'm thinking that i can use reflection to to see what type of object the IList contains and then create a new instance of that type and subsequently add that to the IList itself?

So at any one time I might be processing

```
IList<Customer> l;
```

and I'd like to create a new instance of Customer

```
Customer c = new Customer(0, "None")
```

and then add that onto the list

```
l.Add(c);
```

Obviously doing this dynamically at run-time is the crux of the problem. Hope somebody can give me some pointers. Thanks brendan

Comment: A tip you should state your Lang i guess its c# but it should be in there some where....

Comment: yes, i just realised that when viewing the question myself, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public static void AddNewElement<T>(IList<T> l, int i, string s)
    {
        T obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { i, s });
        l.Add(obj);
    }
```

Usage:

```
    IList<Customer> l = new List<Customer>();
    l.Add(new Customer(1,"Hi there ..."));

    AddNewElement(l, 0, "None");
```

**(EDIT):**

Try this then:

```
    public static void AddNewElement2(IList l, int i, string s)
    {
        if (l == null || l.Count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(l[0].GetType(), new object[] { i, s });
        l.Add(obj);
    }
```

Comment: I think this will work but the manner in which I'm processing the lists doesn't allow for it. i.e. 
foreach (IList l in arrayOfPopulatingLists)
{
    AddNewElement(l, 0, "None")
}
//Compiler error:Arguments for method cannot be inferred from usage.
Do i need to look into calling generic methods?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a parameterless constructor and set the properties afterwards then you can make your method generic, something like:-

```
    void Process<T>(IList<T> list, int x, string y) where T : MyBase, new()
    {
        T t = new T();
        t.X = x;
        t.Y = y;
        list.Add(t);
    }
```

Where MyBase is the base for your classes which expose the int and string properties.  You can use an interface rather than a base class if you want.

Comment: This code doesn't work, and there's nothing similar to achieve this effect.

Comment: Oops, you are correct, have edited the post accordingly.  Thanks

Comment: This looks good. In terms of usage. I have an arrayList of IList's which i'm processing in a foreach. So foreach(IList l in arrayOfILists) { Process(l, 0, "None"); } isn't going to compile which being new to generics i don't see why not (?)

Comment: So that means you want to act on a non-generic IList?  In your question you said that you want to act on a generic IList<T> giving IList<Customer> as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) method to invoke a constructor for a class via its type name (as a string) or an instance of `System.Type`.

Comment: The problem here is that type(s) is/are in a different assembly so i don't believe i can call Activator.CreateInstance

Comment: As long as the assembly is properly loaded, this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your design. You can use [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Using reflection would degrade performance.

Here is code for factory.

```
public abstract class MyStore {
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract void AddItem(int id, string name);
}
```

You can consider using interface if your abstract class has no code.

Then create Customer store.

```
public class CustomerStore : MyStore, IEnumerable<Customer> {
    List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();

    public override string Name { get { return "Customer Store"; } }
    public override void AddItem(int id, string name) {
        list.Add(new Customer(id, name));
    }
    public IEnumerator<Customer> GetEnumerator() {
        return list.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
foreach (MyStore store in List<MyStore>)
    store.AddItem(0, "None");
```

If you want to consider type of store, use

```
switch (store.Name) {
case "Customer Store":
    SomeMethod((CustomerStore)store);
    break;
default:
    throw new WhatEverException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Type.GetGenericArguments method to return the type argument of the generic type IList<T>. Then invoke the appropriate constructor.

```
  Type T = l.GetType ( ).GetGenericArguments ( ) [ 0 ];
  ConstructorInfo ctor = T.GetConstructor (
    new Type [ 2 ] { typeof ( int ), typeof ( string ) } );
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert ( ctor != null );
  object instance = ctor.Invoke (
    new object [ 2 ] { 0, "None" } );
```

Answer (score 0):

The big problem here is:  If you don't know the type, how do you know how to make a new one?  Not every type in the world has a constructor that takes an int and a string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sorry i should have mentioned that the set of objects i will be processing will have a constructor that accepts an int and a string.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the type of the IList is to **look at the property type of the indexer**!

```
var collectionType = targetList.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType;
var constructor = collectionType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
var newInstance = constructor.Invoke(null);
```