# Add new row to Datagrid in a UserControl WPF/VB

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, row, addition

I'm trying to create a UserControl which consists of a DataGrid and a couple of buttons. The buttons will handle adding/deleting rows (needs to be buttons). The DataGrid is bound to a custom observable collection. The collections properties will vary (so I'm auto-generating the columns).

How can I add a new row? Normally I'd just modify the observable collection. I've tried adding a new row directly to the control:

```
dgMain.Items.Add(New DataGridRow())
```

but I get an error which doesn't mean much to me:

> Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Here's the current code behind:

```
Public Class DataGrid

Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

#Region "Dependency Properties"
Public Shared MyItemsSourceProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyItemsSource", GetType(IEnumerable), GetType(DataGrid))
Public Property MyItemsSource() As IEnumerable
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(MyItemsSourceProperty), IEnumerable)
    End Get
    Set(value As IEnumerable)
        SetValue(MyItemsSourceProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

#End Region

#Region "Buttons"
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    dgMain.Items.Add(New DataGridRow())
End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

So does anyone know how I can add a new row?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: This is how the data is created:

```
Dim np As New ObPerson
np.Add(New Person With {.FirstName = "Jane", .LastName = "Mitel", .Age = 18})
np.Add(New Person With {.FirstName = "Joe", .LastName = "Bloggs", .Age = 92})

UserControlInstance.MyItemsSource = np

Public Class ObPerson
    Inherits ObservableCollection(Of Person)
End Class
```

EDIT2: VB Version of the accepted answer:

```
Public Shared Sub AddNewElement(l As IList)
    If l Is Nothing OrElse l.Count = 0 Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException()
    End If
    Dim obj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(l(0).[GetType]())
    l.Add(obj)
End Sub

Usage: AddNewElement(MyItemsSource)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an item directly to ItemsSource (the collection)? The clue is in the error... you've bound to ItemsSource but the grid doesn't support adding/removing via Items.Add. Use ItemsSource (or the original collection). You can cast ItemsSource to the original collection type if you can't get a reference to the original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the collection that's bound - not the 'Items' property on the grid. ItemsSource will point to your collection that is bound:

```
SomeGrid.ItemsSource = SomeCollection;

SomeCollection.Add(new ItemOfTheRightType());
```

or

```
(SomeGrid.ItemsSource as SomeCollection).Add(new ItemOfTheRightType());
```

The error says that you can't use Grid.Items if you are binding using Grid.ItemsSource

Edit:

If you don't know the item type at runtime (maybe because this is a 3rd party using the control etc and you want a generic add method) you need to call the .Add method on the underlying interface. Most list types inherit from IList in the .NET framework

I'm no VB expert, I much prefer c# so I'll give you the c#. You need to check for the underlying type first:

in c#

```
if(grid.ItemsSource is IList) 
{
    (grid.ItemsSource as IList).Add(new childType()); <-- other issue here..
}
```

The problem you have though is that if you are adding a new item to the collection and you don't know the list type, IList requires an instance of the object to add to the list

- solution is to use reflection:

[Dynamically creating a new instance of IList's type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511315/dynamically-creating-a-new-instance-of-ilists-type)

An interesting late answer is:

```
var collectionType = targetList.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType; 
var constructor = collectionType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes); 
var newInstance = constructor.Invoke(null);
```

Which might work

Comment: Hey Charleh, Thanks for the response and explaining the error. I've moved the ItemSource declaration out of XAML and into code as you suggest (Me.dgMain.ItemsSource = MyItemsSource) but the collection (MyItemsSource as IEnumerable) doesn't have an "add" function associated with it. What am I missing!?

Comment: I didn't say to move the delcaration out of XAML, by all means keep it in there. The less code behind the better. You need to be casting to your bound type - is the type of the collection that is bound to the grid an ObservableCollection<x> where x is the item type? If so you need to cast to that - that will have the .Add method

Comment: Ok thanks. How can I cast if I don't know what the item type is? I've added a typical use of the user control to my original question

Comment: Charleh, thanks for walking me through this I've got it working now! I've added the VB version of the answer to my original question in case anyone else needs it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Looks ok - but won't work if you have no items in the list, but if you aren't bothered about that then it will work a charm :) (also it probably won't work if there is no default constructor on the object...but that's the programmers problem!)